# How to correctly implement a Map that has objects as keys?

Tags: dart

I'm trying to implement this logic: I have a deck with several cards. Each card has a suit and a value. However, there may be repeated cards in the deck. I want to count how many of each card are in the deck. Suits are an enum and there's also a `Card` class:

```
enum Suit { Red, Green, Blue };

class Card {
  Suit suit;
  int value;

  Card(this.suit, this.value);
}
```

This would be the deck:

```
final deck = Map<Card, int>();

final addCardToDeck = (Card c) {
  if (deck[c] != null) deck[c]++;
  else deck[c] = 1;
};
```

So let's say I put 2 equal cards in the deck.

```
final cardA = Card(Suit.red, 7);
final cardB = Card(Suit.red, 7);

addCardToDeck(cardA);
addCardToDeck(cardB);
```

Since the two cards are equal, I would expect `deck[cardA]` and `deck[cardB]` to return 2, right? Wrong! Both returned 1. So I thought, ok, must be an object reference problem, I'll overload the `==` operator.

```
bool operator ==(otherCard) {
    return otherCard is Card 
      && suit == otherCard.suit 
      && value == otherCard.value;
}
```

And it still doesn't work as expected. So, how would I correctly implement this? I know I could just make a Map of Maps, so I would access it like `deck[suit][value]`, but I find this approach neater. Is this feasible?

Whole code below.

```
enum Suit { Red, Blue, Green }

class Card {
  Suit suit;
  int value;

  Card(this.suit, this.value);

  bool operator ==(otherCard) {
    return otherCard is Card && suit == otherCard.suit && value == otherCard.value;
  }
}

void main() {
  final deck = Map<Card, int>();

  final addCardToDeck = (Card c) {
    if (deck[c] != null) deck[c]++;
    else deck[c] = 1;
  };

  final cardA = Card(Suit.Red, 7);
  final cardB = Card(Suit.Red, 7);

  addCardToDeck(cardA);
  addCardToDeck(cardB);

  print(deck[cardA]); // Expected 2, got 1
  print(deck[cardB]); // Expected 2, got 1
}
```

Comment: Heads up I corrected a bug in my solution (the hash code calculation was bad)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`hashCode` will be used to determine equality in a `Map`. If you override `==` you should also override `hashCode`

https://dart.dev/guides/language/effective-dart/design#equality

Here is the updated code:

```
enum Suit { Red, Blue, Green }

class Card {
  Suit suit;
  int value;

  Card(this.suit, this.value);

  @override
  bool operator ==(otherCard) {
    return otherCard is Card &&
        suit == otherCard.suit &&
        value == otherCard.value;
  }

  @override
  int get hashCode => suit.hashCode^value.hashCode;
}

void main() {
  final deck = <Card, int>{};

  final addCardToDeck = (Card c) {
    if (deck[c] != null) {
      deck[c]++;
    } else {
      deck[c] = 1;
    }
  };

  final cardA = Card(Suit.Red, 7);
  final cardB = Card(Suit.Red, 7);
  final cardC = Card(Suit.Green, 4);

  addCardToDeck(cardA);
  addCardToDeck(cardB);
  addCardToDeck(cardC);

  print(deck[cardA]); // Expected 2, got 2
  print(deck[cardB]); // Expected 2, got 2
  print(deck[cardC]); // Expected 1, got 1
}
```